# Want Div shifted to the right,

Tags: html, css

I want my btn class to be shifted right. I have two button classes eg. btn-full, btn-ghost, I want to shift both of them to the right, if I float it to right then their position changes, I don't know why.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Musica</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="hero-text-box">
            <h1>Life is the Song.<br> Love is the Music.</h1>
            <a class= "btn btn-full" href="#">Listen </a>
            <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato','Arial',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.row{
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),url(img/hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.hero-text-box{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1{
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 240%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 4px;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 200px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited{
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    border: 1px solid #2ecc71;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited{
    border: 1px solid #2ecc71;
    color: #2ecc71;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active{
    background-color: #1e874b;
}

.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active{
    border: 1px solid #1e874b;
}

.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active{
    border: 1px solid #1e874b;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I tried everything like  float:right, the position:absolute; ;left:-5oo; but it doesnot work. Please help

Comment: For starts I'd remove the space between the '=' and the '"': x <a class= "btn  if that is in the actual code it will break it.

Comment: If you want them to shift to the right... why use a `float: left;`?

Comment: @AndrewCoder my mistake , i correct it.

Comment: Also, shift them how much? An image of the desired result would be useful here. At the moment this question is too vague.

Comment: @Paulie_D If u see it in a browser , u will know , I just wanted to move these button to the extreme right or right corner.

Comment: Perhaps you need to build a demo then,perhaps in JSfiddle.net to **show** us the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this ?

[image]

```
    <style>

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato','Arial',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.row{
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),url(img/hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.hero-text-box{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align:right;
}

h1{
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 240%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 4px;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 200px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited{
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    border: 1px solid #2ecc71;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited{
    border: 1px solid #2ecc71;
    color: #2ecc71;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active{
    background-color: #1e874b;
}

.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active{
    border: 1px solid #1e874b;
}

.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active{
    border: 1px solid #1e874b;
    color: #fff;
}

</style>







<body>
    <header>
        <div class="hero-text-box">
            <div><h1 style="display:inline-block; text-align:left;">Life is the Song.<br> Love is the Music.</h1></div>
            <a class= "btn btn-full" href="#">Listen </a>
            <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

EXP:

```
.btn:link,
.btn:visited{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 200px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

margin-top: 150px;   //You were trying to manually place the buttons with this line I suggest, you could've get away with it if you adjusted the positioning of the buttons, but this would be a bad practice.

Instead, I just Ordered the div to have its content aligned to the right,
and put the H1 inside a div, then align the H1 to the left in order to have a perfectly left aligned text.

Comment: @ahmed Surely, how did u do that , please explain??

Comment: check the exp, I updated my answer, I didn't wrote it in the first place because you didnt show us what exactly kind of output you were hoping to get.